# How to use Map as an Element in a List (Flutter)

Tags: list, flutter, dart, maps

I am new in flutter and I want to use a Map inside a List of elements.
Basicaly,

var questions = [
{'key' : 'value'},
'anotherElement'
] ;
//and then trying to access it by //passing it into a widget

myWidget(
['value']
)

but this way is not working.
shows error:
The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.

Please let me know how can I use Map inside a List?

Comment: add myWidget code

Comment: `questions` is a heterogeneous `List`.  Since the common base class of `{'key' : 'value'}` and `'anotherElement'` is `Object`, `questions` is inferred to be of type `List<Object>`.  If you want to access one of its elements as a `Map`, you'll need to explicitly cast it, or you need to use a `List<dynamic>` to disable static type-checking.

Comment: Provide your code so someone can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the List type to Map and store the map values into the list collection. Please just refer the below code snippets. I just show you the simple codes to explain the list of map items.

```
void main() {
  List<Map<String, int>> maps = [
    {'one': 1, 'two': 2},
     // Add more map records.
  ];
  
  // Gets the first map item from the maps collection.
  // and gets the value of 'one' key from it.
  print(maps[0]['one']);.     // Prints 1.
}
```